# Algorithm for answering queries of the type "largest interval contained in the given interval"

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, intervals

I have been wondering over the following problem:

Given a set $S$ of intervals on the number line. We can do two operations on them:

1. Add a new interval $[l_i,r_i]$ to $S$
2. Given an interval $[l_j, r_j]$, which is possibly not in $S$, find the longest interval from $S$ which is contained entirely in $[l_j, r_j]$

If I didn't have operation $1$ I have found a solution using a persistent segment tree.

For the full version, there is the trivial solution which runs in $O(QN)$ ($Q$ - number of queries, $N$ - total number of intervals added). I also found that  using interval tree, I can directly find which intervals intersect the query interval and then I can check them manually. However, is there an even better solution? Maybe $O(Q\log N)$ or $O(Q\log^2N)$?

Comment: @thefunkyjunky Please add a reference to the original problem.

Comment: @Apass.Jack sorry, I'll add explanations for Q and N. There is no original problem(you can say I made it up), that's why I am asking if there is a better solution.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your notation. Your first bound is $O(QN)$, which makes me think that what you're measuring includes the time to process *all* queries. Your second bounds, however, don't include $Q$ at all. But if you're processing all queries, the answer must be at least $\Omega(Q)$, since you have to read every query.

Comment: @jbapple, fixed.

Comment: Can you describe your solution using a persistent segment tree?

Comment: @jbapple The idea is to sort the intervals by their left end, then going from the last interval to the first interval. For each interval $[l_i, r_i]$, write $r_i - l_i + 1$ at position $r_i$ in the segment tree. Now for each query $[l_i, r_i]$, "revert" the persistent segment tree so that only intervals with left point $\geq l_i$ are in the segment tree, then query the maximum over $[0, r_i]$

Comment: Couldn't "revert" take $\Omega(N)$ time? What is the "revert" algorithm?

Comment: @jbapple, simply binary search in the sorted intervals (remember, they are sorted by left point)

Comment: Sorry, still not sure how "simply binary search" makes it so "only intervals with left point $\geq l_i$ are in the segment tree". Generally, binary search is a non-modifying operation that doesn't change what objects are in a tree. Overall, I think describing your solution in more detail in your question might be helpful to potential question answerers.

Comment: @jbapple, the binary search is over the sorted list of intervals, with it you can see awhich point in the history of the segment tree you should revert to.